# Workaround for passing parameter pack to alias templates (which have non-pack parameters)

Tags: c++

Look at this example:

```cpp
template <typename A>
struct Foo1 {};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct Foo2 {};

struct Bar1 {
    template <typename A>
    using Foo = Foo1<A>;
};

struct Bar2 {
    template <typename A, typename B>
    using Foo = Foo2<A, B>;
};

template <typename BAR>
struct Something {
    template <typename ...P>
    void func(typename BAR::template Foo<P...> foo) {
    } 
};
```

I'd like to achieve: if `Something` is specialized with `Bar1`, then I'd like to have a template function `func`, which is:

```
   template <typename A>
   void func(Foo1<A> foo)
```

and if `Something` is specialized with `Bar2`, then `func` should be:

```
   template <typename A, typename B>
   void func(Foo2<A, B> foo)
```

However, this straightforward approach doesn't work, because clang complains (you need to instantiate `Something<BarX>` to make clang to report this error):

> error: pack expansion used as argument for non-pack parameter of alias template
> void func(typename BAR::template Foo<P...> foo) {

So it seems that alias templates are not 100% transparent (I found some discussion about this: [CWG 1430](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1430), that this is by design).

Are the any workarounds for this problem?

(gcc compiles this code, but according to CWG 1430, this might be unintended)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround is to make the alias variadic:

```
struct Bar1 {
    template <typename... Ts>
    using Foo = Foo1<Ts...>;
};

struct Bar2 {
    template <typename... Ts>
    using Foo = Foo2<Ts...>;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f8549ra16)